# Telnet IP address slow response on Windows 2019

Tags: windows, networking

My networking knowledge is limited to just Ping, Ipconfig and basics so this question might seem strange or inadequate.  I've installed a custom SMTP server (which I've used successfully on many different machines) on a newly installed Windows 2019 server, and it is responding slowly even using the Telnet test tool on port 25.  SMTP Response 220 takes 15 seconds to return even on test local network that I setup with a switch.

When I tried to run Telnet on the smtp server itself, Telnet IP address also takes almost just as long.  However, Telnet 127.0.0.1 is instantaneous.  Firewall is switched off and there's no 3rd party security software installed that I'm aware of.

Any pointers on how what could have caused the slow network response or what other tests I can do will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, does it's a VM ? did you tried from another VM inside the host ? To isolate if a host problem. (Traffic inside the same host does not hit the physical's switch usually)

Comment: @yagmoth555 It's not a VM.  It's a physical machine.  Strangely, I've other server running also Windows 2019 but does not experience the lag.  Ping isn't affected, only telnet.

Comment: Do you use `telnet IP 25` or you use hostname?

Comment: I'm using telnet IP4 25 on the local machine, not using hostname.  telnet 127.0.0.1 25 has no lag, instantaneous 220 response.